# Calculating arc length

Tags: calculus

The following comes from a tutorial on calculating arc length using integration:

[image]

I need help understanding the third step from the bottom. I know that the $2/3$ out front represents the $3/2$ that the rest of the equation is divided by when we integrate it. I don't, however, understand where the 4 out front comes from. Please help me understand this.

Comment: Can you integrate $(1+5x)^7$?  It's really no different from this.

Comment: I'll remark that, while the predominant mistakes people make in calculus are the usual math mistakes of "sign errors" and "copying errors", omitting the linear coefficient in making the $ \ u-$ substitution in integration (or chain-rule differentiation, for that matter) is one of the most common _calculus_ errors.  "Everyone" makes this mistake at one time or another, so don't feel too badly about missing this.  I bring this up to caution that this one is made often on timed exams, so beware...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes from integration by substitution.

Let $w=1+\frac{1}{4}x$.  Then $dw=\frac{1}{4}\,dx$, or $dx=4\,dw$. So
$$
\int_0^5\sqrt{1+\frac{x}{4}}\,dx=\int_{1+\frac{0}{4}}^{1+\frac{5}{4}}\sqrt{w}\,4\,dw=4\int_1^{9/4}\sqrt{w}\,dw=\left.4\cdot\frac{2}{3}w^{3/2}\right\rvert_{w=1}^{9/4}=\frac{8}{3}\left(\frac{27}{8}-1\right)=\frac{19}{3}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The $4$ out front comes because of the factor $\frac 14$ before the $x$.  If you differentiate $\left( 1+\frac 14x\right)^{3/2}$ we have $$\frac d{dx}\left( 1+\frac 14x\right)^{3/2}=\frac 32\frac d{dx}\left( 1+\frac 14x\right)^{1/2}\frac d{dx}\left( 1+\frac 14x\right)=\frac 14\cdot \frac32\left( 1+\frac 14x\right)^{1/2}$$ and we need to cancel both the leading factors.